# Inter PC connection using .net

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I am trying to set up a basic client-server connection on Linux between two PCs connected on the same network.

I successfully connected my client to my server on my local machine.
But when I give my client the server-PC's ip thanks to the 'ifconfig' command I have : Connection refused.
I already opened the port I use thanks to the command : sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=4242/tcp

Here is how I set the socket connection with "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" the IP address that I get from the 'ifconfig' command (maybe it's not the proper way to do it ?).

```cs
// Establish the remote endpoint
// for the socket.

IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 4242);

// Creation TCP/IP Socket using
Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily,
                    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

Here is the exception output:
SocketException : System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (111): Connection refused xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4242

Comment: Does `telnet xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx 4242` work?

Comment: I'm not seeing a call to `Connect` or  'Bind' in the provided code. Also, your comment states that the remote endpoint is set up, while the code creates `localEndPoint`. Could you show the code for both client and server?

Comment: Well, you have opened TCP port 4242 on your server. But is there actually something configured on the server to listen to that TCP port? It's like opening the window and shouting out of the opened window. But unless there is somebody able to listen, nobody will hear you shouting, so to speak ;-)

Comment: Is the server on same machine as client?  The server should use as an end point IPAny instead of an IP address or localhost.  The connection refuse can occur if two connections have the same combination of source IP and destination IP.

Comment: Have a look at [TcpListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=netcore-2.2) for the server and [TcpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=netcore-2.2) for the client.